# @autowired is null in UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am new to spring boot, I am trying to implement an authentication filter using spring security in my Spring boot app, but I do not understand why when using the @autowired annotation in the tokenService attribute it is null, can someone explain to me why this happens? and what is the correct configuration in java code (I'm not using xml files) so that spring the tokenService attribute is not null.
next I'm going to show you the classes of interest:

```
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Autowired
private TokenService tokenService;//this is null

public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
    try {
        LoginDto creds = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(req.getInputStream(), LoginDto.class);

        return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getEmail(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>())
        );
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                        HttpServletResponse res,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
String token=tokenService.createAuthenticationToken(auth);//nullpointer exception here!
        long expirationTime=tokenService.getExpirationTime(token);
    res.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.getWriter().print("{\"expiresIn\": "+expirationTime+"}");}}
```

and it's my TokenService class:

```
@Component
public class TokenService implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

long expirationTime = new Long(86400000); // 1 day
public static final String SECRET = "SecretKeyToGenJWTs";
public static final long EXPIRATION_TIME = 86_400_000; // 1 day
public static final String TOKEN_PREFIX = "Bearer ";
public static final String HEADER_STRING = "Authorization";

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Autowired
private ProviderService providerService;

public TokenService() {

}

public String createAuthenticationToken(Authentication auth) {
    String token = Jwts.builder().setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername()).setIssuedAt(new Date())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expirationTime))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes()).compact();
    return token;
}

public long getExpirationTime(String token) {
    Claims claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes()).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    Integer intDate = (Integer) claims.get("exp");
    long tokenDate = (intDate.longValue() * 1000);
    return tokenDate;
}

public String getSubjectFromAuthorizationToken(String token) {
    String subject = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes()).parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
            .getBody().getSubject();
    return subject;
}
}
```

And it's my config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan({"com.espiritware.opusclick.security"})

public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

public static final String USER_REGISTRATION_URL = "/v1/users/registration";
public static final String PROVIDER_REGISTRATION_URL = "/v1/providers/registration";
public static final String CONFIRM_REGISTRATION_URL = "/v1/registrationConfirm";
public static final String SEND_RESET_PASSWORD_EMAIL = "/v1/sendResetPasswordEmail";
public static final String RESET_PASSWORD = "/v1/resetPassword";
public static final String LOGIN = "/v1/login";


private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

public WebSecurity(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, USER_REGISTRATION_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PROVIDER_REGISTRATION_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, CONFIRM_REGISTRATION_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SEND_RESET_PASSWORD_EMAIL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, RESET_PASSWORD).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
    return source;
}
```

}

Thanks!

Comment: Can you access `tokenService` inside `attemptAuthentication` method? Is it NULL there too? Also, have you tried to debug your code? Please check whether `Authentication auth` is NULL.

Comment: It's makes no sense, I think. Do you call the filter code inside an object managed by the Spring container? Can you post your web configuration or describe better your context?

Comment: If I change the TokenService attribute to... tokenService = new TokenService (), Works perfectly....

Comment: Does both the classes (TokenService  & JWTAuthenticationFilter) belong to the same package? If the answer is no, you will have to include @ComponentScan annotation

Comment: TokenService,  JWTAuthenticationFilter, JWTAuthorizationFilter and WebSecurity belong to the same package

Comment: Your filter isn't a Spring managed bean and as such will not be processed by Spring.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I too had similar problem while using the `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. Refer below solution which I employed to get things working.

Update the `JWTAuthenticationFilter` constructor to accept the application context as one of the parameters

```
public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, ApplicationContext ctx) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.tokenService= ctx.getBean(TokenService.class);
}
```

Update the config to pass the `ApplicationContext` to the filter instance

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
        // .. some settings
        .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext()))
        // some other settings    
}
```

*Reason for this design approach* - 
The Authentication processing mechanisms supported by Spring security is based on filters which extends [`GenericFilterBean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/GenericFilterBean.html?is-external=true). As per the docs (*emphasis mine*)

> This generic filter base class has **no** dependency on the Spring ApplicationContext concept. Filters usually don't load their own context but rather *access service beans from the Spring root application context*, accessible via the filter's ServletContext (see WebApplicationContextUtils).

Thus we need to supply the `ApplicationContext` to the filter to access the service bean(s).

Let know in comments if you need further information.

**P.S.**: You can consider using the `JWTAuthenticationFilter` as `@Bean` also and refer it in configuration as `.addFilter(jwtAuthFilter())`

```
@Bean
public JWTAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter() throws Exception {
    return new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), getApplicationContext());
}
```

Comment: @AlejoDev Sure, please refer the section titled `Reason for this design approach` added for the same.

Comment: Thanks. That helped:)

Comment: Wow, thanks.  This really helped, far more than the supposedly "duplicate" answer which tells me in great detail what the problem was but not how to fix it.

Comment: Ditto on the above, thanks so much for this!